# c++ eigen A.inverse()*B not equal to A.ldlt().solve(B)

Tags: eigen, solver, matrix-inverse

I would like to compute the trace of the product of two given matrices, say A and B, `Trace(AInv * B)` where `*` is the regular matrix product, `AInv` is the inverse of `A` (being symmetric and positive definite) and `B` is symmetric.

**Solution 1: computing the inverse explicitely**

Noting that `Trace(AInv * B)` is equivalent to taking the sum of the componentwise product of `AInv` and `B`:

```
     double sol1 = (A.inverse().cwiseProduct(B)).sum();
```

**Solution 2: using ldlt decomposition from the Eigen library**

```
     double sol2 = (A.selfadjointView<Lower>().ldlt().solve(B)).trace();
```

Theoretically, these solutions should be the same, but in my test, they don't. Sounds like I am missing something. As `.ldlt().solve()` is not made to compute matrix inverse but rather solve a linear system, my question is : does `.ldlt()` perform any sort of normalization? If not, what I am doing wrong?

Many thanks!

Comment: Generally you would not expect the two results to be identical, due to rounding.  If your matrix is nearly singular, they might be quite different.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Thanks for your comment. By "the same" I mean "approximately" equal. Unfortunately, it's not a matter of rounding, and the matrix is not singular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement to compute `sol1` is wrong: you need to either transpose one of the operands or use a matrix-matrix product: correct versions:

```
double sol1 = (A.inverse().cwiseProduct(B.transpose())).sum();
double sol1 = (A.inverse().lazyProduct(B)).diagonal().sum();
double sol1 = (A.inverse().lazyProduct(B)).trace();
double sol1 = (A.inverse() * B).diagonal().sum();
double sol1 = (A.inverse() * B).trace();
```

Note that, in Eigen, when you write `(A*B).diagonal()` only diagonal elements of `A*B` are computed;, not the off-diagonal ones.

In general, it is not recommended to explicitly compute the inverse of a matrix, and using either `A.lu().solve(B)` or  `A.ldlt().solve(B)` will give you more accurate results and will be faster too because, unless `A` is very small (2, 3, 4), `A.inverse()` is equivalent to `A.lu().solve(I)`. In the future, Eigen will very likely rewrite expressions like:

```
A.inverse() * B
```

as:

```
A.lu().solve(B)
```

for you anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am puzzled, the trace of the product of two matrices is more efficiently computed by my sol1 rather than your 1st sol1. Indeed, by taking the sum of all coefficients of the componentwise product (not the matrix-matrix product), so there is no need in taking the diagonal here, nor computing the off-diagonal matrix elements. So your 1st sol1 seems wrong

Comment: Sorry, I miss read your `cwiseProduct` as `lazyProduct`. The initial code to compute `sol1` is still wrong though. I've updated by answer according.

Comment: Very interesting! The error was indeed in the transpose of the operand, which I didn't make explicit in sol1 as both A and B are symmetric matrices. Many thanks! I would have never found this on my own :S